# How do I connect to a MSSQL database with the Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to connect to a mssql db with the Zend Framework, my application.ini looks like this:

resources.db.adapter = "sqlsrv"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost\SQLExpress"
resources.db.params.username = "****"

resources.db.params.password = "*****"
resources.db.params.dbname = "Database"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

Is there anything wrong with the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources.db.adapter = "sqlsrv"
resources.db.host = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"
resources.db.dbname = "DatabaseName"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true 
resources.db.driver_options.ReturnDatesAsStrings = true
```

No need for Username or Password.

I always use ReturnDatesAsStrings as it is much easier to handle MsSQL in this way.

Comment: Hmm, it still wont work. Maybe a stupid question, but do I need to have some installed or preconfigured within my mssql database?